# Set the value of a variable outside of a fetch call in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-native-fbsdk

I'm writing an app in react native, and I'd like to query and API I have. The API is really simple and just spits out some text on a web page.

I've been using this:

```
var value = '';

fetch("http:myapi.com/")
.then((response) => response)
.then((responseData) => {
  value = responseData._bodyText;
  console.log(responseData._bodyText); //prints what I want
})
.done();

console.log(value); //prints an empty string
```

I'd like to set the value of the var "value" to the response's text. Doing a console.log has shown that responseData._bodyText does have the information I want, but when I try setting the var value to responseData._bodyText, value isn't set and the variable remains empty.

How should I remedy this?

Comment: where are you using the value of "value" ?

Comment: can you update the example with the console.log lines which you refer in the above statement to avoid assumptions...

Comment: Okay I added them

Answer (score 1):

`response` is a response object, and not a promise. You probably want `response.json()` or `response.text()`

```
var value = '';

fetch("http:myapi.com/")
.then((response) => { return response.text() }) // change to return response.text()
.then((text) => {
  value = text;
})
.done();
```

Comment: after resolving first promise with response.text() , how can the chained second promise can have responseData as a object?

Comment: thanks for the update. But why to chain it to 2nd promise? we could assign the text to 'value' in the first promise itself  `.then((response) => value = response.text())`

Comment: @GaleelBhasha because `response.text()` returns a promise that resolves to text. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text. what you suggest would set `value` to a promise and not the text

Comment: This still isn't setting the outside value to the value of text :/

Comment: @higgs perhaps your web service is failing then

Comment: Querying it in a browser works, I'm just sort of confused about how fetch works/why its not working for this

Answer (score 0):

Probably an asynchronous problem. If you were logging out `responseData._bodyText` inside the callback at the end of the fetch promise chain then it would probably be correct but if you were logging the assigned `value` variable and seeing the empty string I would assume you are logging at a point before the fetch promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = '';

fetch("http:myapi.com/")
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((text) => value = text)
.done();
```